# Replacing a single character in a perl regex match

Tags: regex, perl

How can I replace the 6th "_" that appears in the regex match?

Here is the literal input to be searched. It is not representing a path to the input:

```
/Users/rob/Documents/Test/m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_30_0_59.fsa
```

Here is my code, which parses out what I need. I just now need to replace the last matched "_" with a "/":

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(IN, '<', '/Users/roblogan/Test_Database.txt') or die $!;
open(OUT, '>', '/Users/roblogan/Test_Output.txt') or die $!;

while (my $line = <IN>){
        if ($line =~ m/(m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_[0-9]*)/){
            print OUT $1, "\n";
        }
}
```

Current output:

```
m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_30
```

Desired output:

```
m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0/30
```

I have tried:

```
if ($line =~ s/(m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_[0-9]*)/(m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0\/[0-9]*)/){
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your attempt at replacing a character? All I see is testing if an input line matches a very specific case. Do all lines start with `m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_` ? If not, why are you testing for that?

Comment: All lines start with m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p‌​0_. I am only interested in changing the last underscore of the match. There are more underscores outside of the end of the match that I don't need changed. I have shown my attempt at replacing the character in the OP.

Comment: `s#_p0_#_p0/#` should be all you need...

Comment: I am still a student and trying to learn. I am not able yet to answer questions. I have tried to use the substitution s// regex modifier, as shown in my post. I have also tried to make a substring of the match to substitute the "_" for "/" ie substr($line, 62, 1) = "/" but that doesn't work. I have searched stackoverflow and other websites.

Comment: I'd actually suggest that `split /_/` was a better choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, the easiest way is:

```
$line =~ s!(m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p‌​‌​0)_!$1/!
```

I've chosen `!` as the delimiter because `/` is used in the replacement part.

`$1` is a variable containing the text matched by the first `(` `)` group in the regex (I didn't want to repeat the whole thing twice).

The final `_` is not included in `$1` (it's outside of the parens); instead we put `/` in the replacement part.

See [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more information.

Comment: @Borodin It's a judgment call. Sometimes you get beginners who try to make sense of the documentation and they get nowhere. They just have to see a (commented) example to understand what's going on. For example, the `s///` code in the question almost makes sense, it just tries to use a regex on the right-hand side (parens and `[0-9]*`), which is simply not how it works. I posted my answer hoping to help someone achieve understanding (I love light-bulb moments), not for points.

Answer (score 1):

This Perl code will do what I think you need, determined from your subject line and example output

It finds the sixth occurrence of an underscore in the target string and, if that underscore is followed by decimal digits, it changes the underscore to a slash and removes everything following the digits

I have used the pipe character `|` as the delimiter for the substitute operator `s///` to avoid the need to escape forward slashes

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $path = q{/Users/rob/Documents/Test/m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0_30_0_59.fsa};

$path =~ s|^(?:[^_]*_){5}[^_]*\K_(\d+).*|/$1|s;

print $path, "\n";
```

#### output

```
/Users/rob/Documents/Test/m160505_031746_42156_c100980652550000001823221307061611_s1_p0/30
```